# Unable to delete an element from a linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, traversal, singly-linked-list

I am just practicing my data structures and trying to make a method to delete duplicates from a singly linked list. This is what I have:

```
        void removeDup() {
            Node temp = head;
            Node cur = null;
            String s = "";

            while(temp!=null) {
                cur = temp;

                if(!s.contains(temp.data + "")) {
                    s += temp.data + "";
                }
                else {
                    cur.next = temp.next;
                }

                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
```

Printing the linked list after executing this method shows no changes. I believe this is because I am not properly linking the previous link to the current link's.next value, but everything looks correct to me. I debug it and it appears to delete the node correctly but the duplicate node still appears when I print out the linked list afterwards. Suggestions?

Comment: I think you need two loops to find if there is a duplicate (for all combination of two nodes)...

Comment: What about using LinkedHasSet? I believe this is your homework?

Comment: My guess is, the variable s is having the correct output, right?

Comment: No this is not my homework just practice, and @mettleap yes the string s prints out the correct output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is copied from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-linked-list/:

Method 1 - brute force,find all pairs of two nodes to see if they have same values, not sure if calling System.gc() is a good idea:

```
/* Function to remove duplicates from an 
   unsorted linked list */
void remove_duplicates() { 
    Node ptr1 = null, ptr2 = null, dup = null; 
    ptr1 = head; 

    /* Pick elements one by one */
    while (ptr1 != null && ptr1.next != null) { 
        ptr2 = ptr1; 

        /* Compare the picked element with rest 
            of the elements */
        while (ptr2.next != null) { 

            /* If duplicate then delete it */
            if (ptr1.data == ptr2.next.data) { 

                /* sequence of steps is important here */
                dup = ptr2.next; 
                ptr2.next = ptr2.next.next; 
                System.gc(); 
            } else /* This is tricky */ { 
                ptr2 = ptr2.next; 
            } 
        } 
        ptr1 = ptr1.next; 
    } 
}
```

Method 2 - using hashset to help detect duplicate, I personally like this method better:

```
 /* Function to remove duplicates from a 
       unsorted linked list */
    static void removeDuplicate(node head)  
    { 
        // Hash to store seen values, changed a little to compile for Java 8
        HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<Integer>(); 

        /* Pick elements one by one */
        node current = head; 
        node prev = null; 
        while (current != null)  
        { 
            int curval = current.val; 

             // If current value is seen before 
            if (hs.contains(curval)) { 
                prev.next = current.next; 
            } else { 
                hs.add(curval); 
                prev = current; 
            } 
            current = current.next; 
        } 

    }
```

Comment: needed to move cur = temp to inside the add to hashset condition

Comment: the hash set is a helping structure to detect duplicate by checking if the value exists already in the hash set

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think your choice of holding all the previous things in a single string is probably a bad idea.

For example, if you fed it a list with {x,y, xy}.  the third item would be detected as a duplicate.
Couple simple alternative methods.
Hold previous values in some collection/ for each element check if anything else is equivalent.
sort everything, then check peoples neighbors.

you set cur = temp; at the top of your loop,
so doing cur.next = temp.next; afterwards will do nothing.
Don't set cur equal to temp at the top of your loop or just change it after.

Answer (score 0):

`cur.next = temp.next` will not change anything. Use e.g. Java 8:

`new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,1,3)).stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());`

or

`new LinkedHashSet<>(new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,1,3)))`

See also https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-linked-list